# Self-hosted, web-based typeface management?

Tags: website-design, web-fonts, font-management

I'm a web designer/developer, and I use linux. Linux has always been pretty poor with font management, and none of the options will even read woff2 files.

Almost all my font management is for webfonts, and I realized that it would be great if I could just host all my fonts on my server, and preview them in the browser — since this is where they're going to end up, anyway.

I'm looking for a way to preview my webfonts, preview the opentype features like swashes and ligatures, play with the size and colors, and copy the paths to where these files live on the server. Is there anything out there that will let me do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although I completely understand the desire for what is being asked, this boils down to a shopping-list question. Any (useful) answer would most likely merely be a link to some product. And links will rot.